# Drop down parameters based on Condition for Cloud Formation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is there way by which we can change the drop down list of parameters based on one of the above parameters?
If we select "Env: Prod" choice out of Prod/Dev in the dropdown list of environments list, it should list all the VPCs which belongs to Prod environment. Similarly for Dev as well..
Based on those Environment VPCs, it should list available subnets and Security Groups..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That functionality is not yet suported but you can implement some assertions rule for ex.

```
Rules:
  SubnetsInVPC:
    Assertions:
      - Assert: !EachMemberIn [!ValueOfAll ['AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id', VpcId], !RefAll 'AWS::EC2::VPC::Id']
        AssertDescription: All subnets must in the VPC
```

With this, you can make sure that selected values are within or related to the valid range or service parameters.

Comment: Thanks ExploringApple...
I haven't thought of this scenario till now, but I'll check whether it can help us in our requirement